# windows 10(64-bit) python 3.7 (32 bit) install nltk

Tags: python

I used the command 
import nltk 
nltk.download()
for Python 3.7(32bit) on Windows 10, but the Command Prompt gave me the following errors:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'
NameError: name 'nltk' is not defined

Comment: Did you install NLTK?

Comment: The error is telling you that you don't have the module installed properly - how did you install it?

Comment: `pip install nltk` ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [installation page](http://www.nltk.org/install.html) of `nltk`. The simplest way to install it in your case should be:

```
pip install nltk
```

Enter this from your console (before starting `python`). After the command is completed, you should be able to use the commands you posted above.

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: it gives me this error after executing pip install nltk command File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\download.py", line 586, in written_chunks

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full traceback there.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing nltk library.
For installing it use the following command.

> pip install -U nltk